# Rename nodes from namelist in same XML document

Tags: xslt, rename, nodes

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Set>
<Tables>
  <Table>
    <Tablehead>
      <C>Name</C>
      <C>FirstName</C>
      <C>Address</C>
      <C>Zip</C>
      <C>City</C>
      <C>State</C>
    </Tablehead>
    <Rows>
      <Person>
        <C>Miller</C>
        <C>John</C>
        <C>Squires Circle</C>
        <C>88034</C>
        <C>Boulder</C>
        <C>Colorado</C>
      </Person>
    </Rows>
  </Table>
    </Tables>
  </Set>
</Data>
```

The element person can occur n-times. Now to properly work with that structure I have to rename the `<C>` tags first within `<Person>`.
I came up with this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Rows"> 
    <Rows>     
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Person"/>
    </Rows>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person">
     <Person>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="C"/>                    
     </Person>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Data/Set/Tables/Table/Rows/Person/C">
    <xsl:variable name="nodePosition" select="position()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/Tablehead/C[$nodePosition]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output is always this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Set>
  <Tables>
  <Table>
    <Tablehead>
      <C>Name</C>
      <C>FirstName</C>
      <C>Address</C>
      <C>Zip</C>
      <C>City</C>
      <C>State</C>
    </Tablehead>
    <Rows>
      <Person/>
    </Rows>
  </Table>
  </Tables>
  </Set>
</Data>
```

It looks fine but my `<Person>` element is always empty. What am I missing?

Comment: Your XML does not have any `<A>` elements, but your XSLT code is written as if it does. Please explain exactly what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Hello mzjn, Sorry about that. I now corrected my XSLT to match the <C>-tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person/C">
    <xsl:variable name="index">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{../../../Tablehead/C[position() = $index]}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Set>
<Tables>
  <Table>
    <Tablehead>
      <C>Name</C>
      <C>FirstName</C>
      <C>Address</C>
      <C>Zip</C>
      <C>City</C>
      <C>State</C>
    </Tablehead>
    <Rows>
      <Person>
        <C>Miller</C>
        <C>John</C>
        <C>Squires Circle</C>
        <C>88034</C>
        <C>Boulder</C>
        <C>Colorado</C>
      </Person>
    </Rows>
  </Table>
    </Tables>
  </Set>
</Data>
```

outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Data>
  <Set>
<Tables>
  <Table>
    <Tablehead>
      <C>Name</C>
      <C>FirstName</C>
      <C>Address</C>
      <C>Zip</C>
      <C>City</C>
      <C>State</C>
    </Tablehead>
    <Rows>
      <Person>
        <Name>Miller</Name>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <Address>Squires Circle</Address>
        <Zip>88034</Zip>
        <City>Boulder</City>
        <State>Colorado</State>
      </Person>
    </Rows>
  </Table>
    </Tables>
  </Set>
</Data>
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, Your solution works perfectly. Sorry about my mismatch of C and A in my XML/XSLT. I also tried it on a bigger file as well and it worked. Thank you for your help - it looks so easy. I will try to get to understand it. Best regards, Peter